# Support for multiple sample rates during playing and recording in an application like Audacity

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-audio, audacity

This is how I have defined my soundcard's channels in `.asoundrc`:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
       pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default { 
    type hw
    card 1
}

pcm_slave.usb_1 {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
    rate 44100
    channels 8
    buffer_size 4096
    period_size 1024
}

pcm.outch1 {
    type dshare
    ipc_key 1111
    slave usb_1
    bindings [ 0 ]
    hint.description "USB output/playback channel 1 (from output port 1)"
}

pcm.inch1 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 1111
    slave usb_1
    bindings [ 0 ]
    hint.description "USB input/capture channel 1 (from input port 1)"
}
```

While the above **works fine with `aplay` and `arecord`** functions/commands in the terminal, trying to play a 8k audio sample with `Audacity` throws the following error :

[image: Audacity Error]

When I check the `Audio device info` option in `Help` menu (Help-->Audio device option), I see the following:

```
Device ID: 2
Device name: USB Audio (hw:1,0)
Host name: ALSA
Recording channels: 8
Playback channels: 8
Low Recording Latency: 0.008707
Low Playback Latency: 0.008707
High Recording Latency: 0.034830
High Playback Latency: 0.034830
Supported Rates:
    44100
    48000
    88200
    96000
==============================
Device ID: 10
Device name: outch1
Host name: ALSA
Recording channels: 0
Playback channels: 1
Low Recording Latency: -1.000000
Low Playback Latency: 0.023220
High Recording Latency: -1.000000
High Playback Latency: 0.023220
Supported Rates:
    44100
==============================
Device ID: 11
Device name: inch1
Host name: ALSA
Recording channels: 1
Playback channels: 0
Low Recording Latency: 0.023220
Low Playback Latency: -1.000000
High Recording Latency: 0.023220
High Playback Latency: -1.000000
Supported Rates:
==============================
```

As we can see, `8000` or `16000` is not a `Supported Rate` from the audio device info. So, it's quite clear why the error is thrown.

So, how and where can I add/set (modify my `.asoundrc` maybe?) these sample rates so that any application (including `Audacity` of course) can support playback and recording of audio files at any desired sample rate.

Comment: `dmix`/`dshare`/`dsnoop` always use a fixed rate. Try PulseAudio instead.

Comment: @CL. Okay. So, we should replace `dshare` and `dsnoop` with `pulseaudio` plugin?
But still, I want to understand why it works well with the commands `aplay -D plug:outch1 -c 1 -r 8000 play_filename.wav` and `arecord -D plug:inch1 -c 1 -d 20 -f S16_LE -r 8000 rec_filename.wav` and not with `Audacity`?

Comment: The `plug` plugin automatically resamples. If you want that, wrap it around the other plugins.

Comment: Is that possible with `Audacity`? Wrap around I mean.
Could you explain a bit more on this?

Comment: See the `default` PCM device.

Comment: You mean I have replace `plug` with `pulseaudio` plugin?

Comment: No, use `plug` like in the `!default` definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63221/discussion-between-skrowten-hermit-and-cl).

Answer (score 2):

The `dmix`/`dshare`/`dsnoop` plugins always use a fixed sample rate.

To allow the device itself to run at a different rate, use PulseAudio instead.

To resample the data from the application before it goes to the `dshare` plugin, wrap a `plug` plugin around it:

```perl
pcm.outch1 {
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type dshare
        ipc_key 1111
        slave usb_1
        bindings [ 0 ]
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved it! Out of sheer curiosity, I just wanted to ask if there is any disadvantage/drawback of using this automatic conversion plugin `plug`? Which particular cases would I need PulseAudio? It would be great if you could illustrate this.

Comment: With this, the actual hardware device always runs at 44100 Hz.

Comment: Then, the software (that is, ALSA) does the conversion? And with PulseAudio, we can allow the hardware device to run at a different rate according to its capability. Right?

Comment: Also, if I replace type `plug` with `pulse` (plugin), by default `PulseAudio` would be used? I want to make my device run at different rates.

Comment: PulseAudio does not have a `slave`; you would have to configure the one-channel stuff in PA's configuration.